# Call a python script

Tags: python

I have a python script, previously I could call it in multiple ways:

1. double click it;
2. in command line, directly call the script in the folder;
3. use `python script_name.py` to explicitly call it.

But today, I installed an `anaconda` in the system. Now the first two method to call a script will fail. something like `'No module named paramiko'`. but this library is already installed, and `python script_name.py` could run properly.

Any suggestion how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you installed anaconda it can really donk up your python version and libraries. It will often connect to and make changes to your python libraries. You have a few options.

1) uninstall anaconda an see if that helps. If so you need to work on your anaconda install

2) start checking packages in the anaconda command prompt. You can do this

```
conda install -c anaconda paramiko
```

Try number 2 first. If that is the case you will just have to occasionally install libraries that don't come with anaconda on install.

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/paramiko